# Automatically creating textbox in Kentico

Tags: kentico

I want to create pagetype that contains + button or Add, if the user press on it it should create new textbox and user can create any numbers of textboxes as per his needs.

It would save the results then in custom table.

Is their any one who has idea for this regards?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to perform this you'd need to create your own [custom form control](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Example+-+Developing+custom+form+controls).  Depending on what you are needing to do, you may be able to use a different out of the box form control but I'd suggest creating your own custom form control.

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve really great user experience if you implement this with javascript (or any js framework) + Kentico rest service:

- javascript will handle DOM manipulations - adding new text box
- rest service provides api to save data; some [info on rest service](http://bitsorchestra.com/Idea/August-2015/Async-processing-in-Kentico)